# Javascript function not working per functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following Javascript function for expand collapse of the content:

```
function showAns(inp){

        var hide="#hideAns"+inp;
        var show="#showAns"+inp; 
        var ansdiv ="#ans"+inp;
      $(hide).click(function(){
            $(ansdiv).hide(500);
            $(hide).hide();
            $(show).show();
        });
          $(show).click(function(){
            $(ansdiv).show(500);
            $(hide).show();
            $(show).hide();
        });
    }
```

This function is called from following piece of generated HTML code:

```
 <div class="qbox">
        <span class="qclass">Q. No.1) This is test question 112
            <img id ="showAns1" class="icons" src="img/expand.png" onclick="javascript:showAns(1)" alt="show" width="20" height="20" style="float:right; cursor:pointer;">
            <img id="hideAns1" class="icons" src="img/collapse.png" onclick="javascript:showAns(1)" alt="hide" width="20" height="20" style="float:right; display:none; cursor:pointer;">
        </span>
        <img alt="image" class="img" src="img/sample.jpg">
        <hr />
        <span id="ans1">This is test answer 112</span>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="qbox">
        <span class="qclass">Q. No.2) This is test question 110
            <img id ="showAns2" class="icons" src="img/expand.png" onclick="javascript:showAns(2)" alt="show" width="20" height="20" style="float:right; cursor:pointer;">
            <img id="hideAns2" class="icons" src="img/collapse.png" onclick="javascript:showAns(2)" alt="hide" width="20" height="20" style="float:right; display:none; cursor:pointer;">
        </span>
        <hr />
        <span id="ans2">This is test answer 110</span>
    </div>
    <br>
```

problem here is that I have to click thrice the image first time then only expand collapse works fine. Once I click the image twice after that expand collapse works fine. I don't know what I am doing wrong, any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the rendered html, there are many alternative easy ways to accomplish your needs.

Comment: mind making a jsfiddle?

Comment: As you are using jQuery. Why on earth you are using inline event handlers? And In function `showAns()` You are only binding events not executing them

Comment: And of course I am new to jQuery so my code may look stupid.

Comment: The code you posted binds events to the elements, so that when that element is clicked it will expand/collapse. You want to run that code on `$(document).ready()` not as an `onClick` event. It works the second time because after you click it the first time, it has bound the events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do like this

```
$("[id^=ans]").hide();
$(".icons").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("span").find("img").toggle();
    $(this).closest(".qbox").find("[id^=ans]").slideToggle();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/272/)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use class selector and bind events using jQuery. Here is an example.

*HTML*

```
<div class="qbox">
    <span class="qclass">QUESTION
        <img class="show icons" src="img/expand.png" alt="show" >
        <img class="hide icons" src="img/collapse.png" alt="hide" >
    </span>
    <hr />
    <span class="ans">Answer</span>
</div>
```

*Script*

```
$('.qbox .show').click(function(){
    var closestQbox = $(this).closest('.qbox');
    closestQbox.find('.ans').show(500);
    closestQbox.find('.hide').show();
    $(this).hide();
});
$('.qbox .hide').click(function(){
    var closestQbox = $(this).closest('.qbox');
    closestQbox.find('.ans').hide(500);
    closestQbox.find('.show').show();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

---

A simplified version of script

```
$(".ans, .hide").hide();
$('.qbox .icons').click(function () {
    var closestQbox = $(this).closest('.qbox');
    closestQbox.find('.ans, .hide, .show').toggle();
});
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/Z325g/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$(function(){
  $('.icons').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings().show();
        $(this).closest('.qbox').find('[id^=ans]').toggle(500);
  });

});
```